# Funky Responsive CSS

Tags: css

I have a problem with my responsive css. Once I get down to a screen width of about 500px I get a green background going down my entire page.

If anyone can help I would appreciate it. I think it is coming from my .widget-title which I want to stay the same.

```
http://69.195.124.68/~discowv9/?page_id=7
```

Thanks in advance.

Matt

Comment: Could you give more details about the problem? The background is green everywhere, and gets darker at the bottom.

Comment: Obviously I am not having a problem with the background of the website. If you set your browser width to less than 500px you will see that a long green bar stretches from the top of the content area down to the bottom. As I said it was in one of my widget styles (not the background of the site).

Answer (score 1):

It's an element which is called h3 with .widgetTitle class applied to it. To be precise it's the heading background from Quick Links.

When you reduce the size of your page the h3 tag stays at the same height and when the useful links get pushed all the way to the bottom the h3 tag stretches all the way across to it leaving a big green background trail behind it. (Scroll down and see for yourself.)

I'll check your HTML structure and CSS and see if I can figure out what's wrong with it.

In your class .widget-area add this line of code:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

This will fix your issue.

Comment: No problem mate, hope it is the best answer!

Answer (score 1):

your float is not cleared ,
update your css .widget-area, by adding clear:both; line 446

ex:

```
.widget-area {
margin: 0 0 3.3rem;
background-color: #FFF;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
border: 1px solid #a5a5a5;
padding: 0 0.857143rem 0 0.857143rem;
width: 20%;
min-width: 195px;
clear: both;
}
```

Comment: When you clear the widget-area it will not float on the side in normal size. It fixes the issue when resized to under 500px.

Comment: why dou you even need float left for "#content", remove the float then

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. The one above did though. Thanks for your help!